# How can I summarize the properties of two different constructor functions?

Tags: javascript

I create a method "getDamage", which should return either the base damage of the character or, damage of  him weapons assigned to it (if any) and add  base damage to him

```js
 function Weapon(name,damage) { // properties of weapons
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
    }
    Weapon.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this.name + this.damage + " damage"; // method to show weapon
    };
    var bow = new Weapon('Golden bow, ', 20); // create weapon 
    function Character() {
        this.health = 100;
        this.basicDamage = 10; 
        this.toString = function () {
            return this.name + this.weapon + this.heroDamage; // show hero his weapon and stack damage
        };
    Character.createArcher = function () { // create hero 
        var hero = new Character;
        hero.name = "Legolas";
        return hero;
    };
  Character.prototype.setWeapon = function (weapon) {
        var me = this;
        me.weapon = weapon; // contact with weapon
        return me;
    };
    Character.prototype.getDamage = function (heroDamage) {
    var stack = this.basicDamage + this.damage;
    stack.heroDamage = heroDamage;
    return stack;
};
    var archer = new Character.createArcher();
    archer.setWeapon(bow); // set the selected weapon
    console.log(archer.toString());
```

Comment: What type do you expect `stack` to be?

Comment: I guess you're looking for `this.weapon.damage` instead of `this.damage`.

Comment: Where is `getDamage` called?

Answer (score 1):

```
    New edited complete answer

    `
    /*Weapon Constructor*/
    function Weapon(name,damage) { // properties of weapons
       this.name = name;
       this.damage = damage;
    }

    /*Weapon Methods*/    
    Weapon.prototype.toString = function () {
      return this.name + this.damage + " damage"; // method to show weapon
    };

    /*Character Constructor*/
    function Character() {
      this.health = 100;
      this.basicDamage = 10; 
      this.toString = function () {
          return this.heroName + this.weapon.name + this.heroDamage; // show hero his weapon and stack damage
       };
    }

    /*Character methods
    */
    /*Pass weapon object to this method to set weapon details for character*/
    Character.prototype.setWeapon = function (weapon) {
       this.weapon = weapon;
    };

    Character.prototype.createArcher = function (heroName) { // create hero
        this.heroName = heroName;        
    };

    Character.prototype.getDamage = function (weapon) {
       this.heroDamage = this.basicDamage + weapon.damage;
       return this.heroDamage;   
    };

var bow = new Weapon('Golden bow, ', 20);

bow.toString(); //output: "Golden bow, 20 damage"

var archer = new Character();

archer.createArcher('Legolas');

archer.setWeapon(bow);

archer.getDamage(archer.weapon); //output: 30

archer.toString();
//output: "LegolasGolden bow, 30"



    `
```

Comment: what is res? Can you edit the changes you made to make it worked till you get undefined? That would make it more clear what is next thing to fix.

Comment: res - i mean message from method "console.log(archer.toString());"

Comment: I want the method "getDamage" to summarize the base damage and damage from the weapon (if it is set), the corresponding result is output via "toString"

Comment: yes you do not need to do `console.log(archer.toString());`
Just do `archer.toString()`. I will try to fix getDamage.

Comment: @IgorShvets check the edited answer I hope it helps you.